# Can you register a directshow filter without admin?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow

I would like to register a virtual directshow source device without needing admin. On another post I saw someone reference that you can register COM classes per user account via HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. This worked, and I could register the class through HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes without UAC.

To get the source/filter to appear I need to make a call to `IFilterMapper2::RegisterFilter`. This fails without UAC privledge. (`E_ACCESSDENIED General access denied error.`).

Microsoft isn't exactly clear on what the call to RegisterFilter actually does. I know it creates a registry entry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\category clsid\Instance\filter clsid` but one of the key values is FilterData which is a binary value that should theoretically match https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/ns-strmif-regfilter2 this struct; but the data doesn't totally line up so they must write other data in there too.

Is there anyway to register the filter on the user account level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to register the server:

```
STDAPI AMovieSetupRegisterServerOverride(CLSID clsServer, LPCWSTR szDescription, LPCWSTR szFileName, LPCWSTR szThreadingModel = L"Both", LPCWSTR szServerType = L"InprocServer32")
{
    TCHAR achTemp[MAX_PATH];

    OLECHAR szCLSID[CHARS_IN_GUID];
    HRESULT hr = StringFromGUID2(clsServer, szCLSID, CHARS_IN_GUID);

    HKEY hkey;
    DWORD d;
    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%ls"), szCLSID);
    LONG lreturn = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, (LPCTSTR)achTemp, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hkey, &d);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lreturn)
    {
        return AmHresultFromWin32(lreturn);
    }

    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("%ls"), szDescription);
    lreturn = RegSetValue(hkey, (LPCTSTR)NULL, REG_SZ, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp));
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lreturn)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
        return AmHresultFromWin32(lreturn);
    }
    HKEY hsubkey;

    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("%ls"), szServerType);
    lreturn = RegCreateKeyEx(hkey, achTemp, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hsubkey, &d);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lreturn)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
        return AmHresultFromWin32(lreturn);
    }
    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("%ls"), szFileName);
    lreturn = RegSetValue(hsubkey, (LPCTSTR)NULL, REG_SZ, (LPCTSTR)achTemp, sizeof(TCHAR) * (lstrlen(achTemp) + 1));
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lreturn)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
        RegCloseKey(hsubkey);
        return AmHresultFromWin32(lreturn);
    }
    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("%ls"), szThreadingModel);
    lreturn = RegSetValueEx(hsubkey, TEXT("ThreadingModel"), 0L, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE*)achTemp, sizeof(TCHAR) * (lstrlen(achTemp) + 1));

    RegCloseKey(hkey);
    RegCloseKey(hsubkey);

    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lreturn);

}

STDAPI
AMovieSetupUnregisterServerOverride(CLSID clsServer)
{
    OLECHAR szCLSID[CHARS_IN_GUID];
    HRESULT hr = StringFromGUID2(clsServer, szCLSID, CHARS_IN_GUID);
    TCHAR achBuffer[260];
    wsprintf(achBuffer, TEXT("CLSID\\%ls"), szCLSID);
    hr = EliminateSubKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, achBuffer);
    return NOERROR;
}
```

This is copied from the winsdk method, but modified to use the Software\Classes registry instead to avoid UAC:

```
AMovieSetupRegisterServer
```

[Found Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/deps/third_party/winsdk_samples_v71/+/373e927dc5ffdb61b9fb63da3d261e71f8d50dc8/Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/dllsetup.cpp)

Then you can register the filter using the following code (note, I didn't finish figuring out exactly how to serialize the filter data so I registered it with UAC, checked what the binary data was for that, and manually fill it out that way. If you want to serialize the filter data yourself you can [reverse how they do it in GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/blob/5c997e960e5886496421fcda77605314a7399097/src/dsutil.cpp) (method FilterTemplate::LoadFilterData)

```
// {ae7416c6-637d-4b8e-970d-24af9a1dd02a}
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_EXAMPLE_GUID,
    0xae7416c6, 0x637d, 0x4b8e, 0x97, 0x0d, 0x24, 0xaf, 0x9a, 0x1d, 0xd0, 0x2a);

HRESULT RegisterCurrentUser(REGFILTER2 rf)
{
    TCHAR achTemp[MAX_PATH];

    OLECHAR szCLSID[CHARS_IN_GUID];
    HRESULT hr = StringFromGUID2(CLSID_EXAMPLE_GUID, szCLSID, CHARS_IN_GUID);

    HKEY hkey;
    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\{860BB310-5D01-11d0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\\Instance\\%ls"), szCLSID);
    hr = RegCreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, (LPCTSTR)achTemp, &hkey);

    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("%ls"), szCLSID);
    hr = RegSetValueEx(hkey, TEXT("CLSID"), 0L, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE*) achTemp, sizeof(TCHAR) * (lstrlen(achTemp) + 1));

    DWORD data[20];
    data[0] = 0x00000002; //Version
    data[1] = 0x00200000; //Merit
    data[2] = 0x00000001; //if v===1, pin#
    data[3] = 0x00000000; //if v==2, pin #
    data[4] = 0x33697030;
    data[5] = 0x08000000;
    data[6] = 0x00000000;
    data[7] = 0x00000001;
    data[8] = 0x00000000;
    data[9] = 0x00000000;
    data[10] = 0x33797430;
    data[11] = 0x00000000;
    data[12] = 0x00000038;
    data[13] = 0x00000048;
    data[14] = 0x73646976;
    data[15] = 0x00100000;
    data[16] = 0xAA000080;
    data[17] = 0x719B3800;
    data[18] = 0x00000000;
    data[19] = 0x00000000;


    hr = RegSetValueEx(hkey, TEXT("FilterData"), 0L, REG_BINARY, (BYTE*)data, sizeof(data));

    wsprintf(achTemp, TEXT("%ls"), L"Example Filter");
    hr = RegSetValueEx(hkey, TEXT("FriendlyName"), 0L, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE*) achTemp, sizeof(TCHAR) * (lstrlen(achTemp) + 1));
    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Registration information is under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` so you have to have local admin account and elevated privileges for the registration to happen.

Comment: Given that it registers it under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Classes/CLSID/ and I’m pretty sure the system enumerator checks HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID is there any reason it doesn’t work other than that because the registerfilter function is hard coded to reference the local machine path? If I write my own registry entry with the information under HKEY_CURRENT_USERS instead of using the ::RegisterFilter since it gets merged with the local machine classes as HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT won’t it work?

Comment: I think COM registration information can go into HKCU and so you would rely on COM instantiation subsystem (inside CoCreateInstance) that pick up registration data from HKCU instead. This part can work out. The problem is that `RegisterFilter` writes other pieces of information to HKLM and, most importantly, DirectShow Intelligent Connect looks for this information exactly there, without a notion that parts of this data might be under HKCU as well.

Comment: I see what you’re trying to say and I understand that. I don’t specifically care about intelligent connect; but I think intelligent connect not working is a by product of the system enumerator not seeing the filter. I setup auditing through group policy and used event viewer to try and see what registry values were being written, from my quick tests it appeared that the registry value I mentioned above is the only key added. My theory is if I can figure out what order it converts the REGFILTER2 struct into the binary FilterData value I can emulate the register filter function for a local user

Comment: The FilterData values are of known format (these should be the serialized [`REGFILTER2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/ns-strmif-regfilter2) data). The thing is the values are still under HKLM, not HKCU. You need access to write them even if you want to make it around `RegisterFilter`.

Comment: But that’s the beauty of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. If the system enumerator is looking at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID and not HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID my method should work. I don’t see why it wouldn’t just use the class root (to register the com object I reimplement AMovieSetupRegisterServer from streamasd.lib and do the exact same thing where I use the HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead). It works because HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is all the files in both current user and local machine for software/classes

Comment: I think you can give your method a quick test. Register your filter as admin and identify the added FilterData value. Then move it to repsective HKCU where you expect it to be picked up by OS registry blending. After that try some app that works with cameras (or GraphEdit) and check if it still sees your filter. If this works out (I think it should not, but I am not sure) you can proceed with overriding standard regiastration, which is quite a trivial task then.

Comment: FYI GraphStudioNext source code should have code that works with FilterData values. [This](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/blob/39da9fec961a4178c7519544fc369e716aa6931d/src/object_details.cpp#L228) should be a good starting point.

Comment: That’s what I was gonna try when I get home. My issue last night when I stopped working on it was that filter data didn’t match how I expected it to be serialized. In the struct the first two definitions in order are a dword for version, then a dword for merit. In the filterdata, the first dword matched merit, the 2nd dword was 00000000, the 3rd matched version, then the 4th was 00000020. Looking at the graph studio next source should be a good starting point though

Comment: Looks like int FilterTemplate::LoadFilterData in dsutil.cpp is exactly what I needed

Comment: As an update, you can infact register a video source per user dynamically so that you can have the video source register and unregister for the duration of your program without any calls that require admin access. But then I seem to have run into a wall with other things (dynamic format changes for resizing) so it looks like I’ll have to abandoned the directshow approach completely

Comment: @Caps Can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @letmaik Just added it.